# Insertion sort in Python

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I have a homework assignment in Python and ran into a brain freeze. So i'm supposed to do O(nˇ2) exercise using insertion sort.
For example i have a two lists [] and [5,8,1,1] and the program should insert values from one list to another by removing from first and in correct order into another:
[][5,8,1,1] = [5][8,1,1] = [5,8][1,1] = [1,5,8][1] = [1,1,5,8][]

I've came up with something, don't know if i'm on right track but this seems the most reasonable. Indents are in order but copying code here somehow messed it up. 
P.S sorry for Estonian language, it's compulsory to write code in Estonian.

```
def pisteMeetod2(t2ishulk):
    tulemus = [] #new list
    hulgacopy = t2ishulk[0:len(t2ishulk)] #main list
    for el in t2ishulk: #going through first list
        if not tulemus: #if list empty (which it at the beginning is) then from here
            tulemus.append(el)
            del hulgacopy[0]
        else:
            for elemendid in tulemus: #check if there is a lower element from new list
                n = 0
                if hulgacopy[0] <= tulemus[n]:
                    tulemus.insert(n-1,el)
                    del hulgacopy[0]
                    break
                n = n + 1
```

So right now i'm in trouble what do to with second loop. After it has finished checking for elements in result list called "tulemus" and if it does not find any matches how should i continue my code so it would append the "el" into tulemus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `else` clause to the inner `for` loop:

```
for elemendid in tulemus: #check if there is a lower element from new list
    n = 0
    if hulgacopy[0] <= tulemus[n]:
        tulemus.insert(n, el)
        del hulgacopy[0]
        break
    n = n + 1
else:
    tulemus.append(el)
    del hulgacopy[0]
```

Its body gets executed if the loop wasn't terminated using `break`. You can read more about `else` clauses on loops in Python's [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Please also note that if you find an insertion point while iterating, you should use `tulemus.insert(n, el)` instead of `tulemus.insert(n-1, el)` to insert the current element there. Otherwise you'll end up inserting at the end of the list (index -1) when `n == 0`.